# Error al convertir json a objeto de JS

Tags: php, javascript, json, mysqli

alguien sabe por que me sale este error? 
anteriormente tenia un error y era por un echo en el php de la base de datos pero ya no lo tengo y cambio la posicion de el error a 60

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 60
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload
```

estos son los datos que obtiene y manda a la base de datos pero tengo un problema cuando lo intento convertir a objeto

```
     {"nombre":"1","empresa":"2","telefono":"3","accion":"crear"}{"respuesta":"correcto","info":{"affected_rows":null,"insert_id":null,"num_rows":null,"param_count":null,"field_count":null,"errno":null,"error":null,"error_list":null,"sqlstate":null,"id":null}}
```

este es mi javascript, no tengo nada anormal

```
function eventListeners(){
        // cuando el formulario de crear o editar se ejecuta
        formularioContactos.addEventListener('submit', leerFormulario); 
    }
    function leerFormulario(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //aca abajo se asignan los valores y no hay nada anormal
        const nombre = $('#nombre').val(),
            empresa = $('#empresa').val(),
            telefono = $('#telefono').val(),
            accion = $('#accion').val();
        if (nombre === '' || empresa === '' || telefono === ''){
            mostrarNotificacion('todos los campos son obligatorios', 'error');
        }else{
            //pasa la validacion creada a AJAX
            const infoContacto = new FormData();
            infoContacto.append("nombre", nombre);
            infoContacto.append("empresa", empresa);
            infoContacto.append("telefono", telefono);
            infoContacto.append("accion", accion);

            if(accion === 'crear'){
                    //crear nuevo contacto  
                    insertarBD(infoContacto);
            }else{
                //editar el contactos
            }

            // mostrarNotificacion('contacto creado correctamente', 'correcto')
        }
    }
        function insertarBD(datos){

            //crear el objeto
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //abrir la conexion
            xhr.open('POST', 'inc/modelos/modelo-contactos.php', true);

            //pasar los datos
            xhr.onload = function(){    
                if(this.status === 200){
                    console.log(xhr.responseText)
                   /*esta linea de abajo es la que me tira error*/
                    const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
            //enviar los datos
            xhr.send(datos);
```

Comment: Hola Joaquin, a simple vista tenes un **uno** (`1`) antes de la apertura de llaves `{`. Ese uno, puede deverse a que estas haciendo `echo` de una variable o algo similar

Comment: Hola Marcos, gracias por tu respuesta, el 1 era de un echo $conn->ping(); pero lo saque y sigue saliendo lo mismo, ya edite la publicacion y agregue de mi codigo javascript

Comment: Ahora el problema parece ser que estas imprimiendo **dos** `JSON`. Uno que contiene `{"nombre":"1","empresa":"2","telefono":"3","accion":"crear"}` y el otro que contiene el resto. Eso esta mal, si necesitas imprimir ambos, entonces los tenes que unir e imprimir solo la union de ambos arreglos u objetos

Comment: Si el problema es al generar el JSON ... ¿¿ Para que muestras el código en Javascript ?? ¿¿ Porqué no proporcionas un [mcve] en PHP ??

Comment: solucionado, era que habia dos JSON

Comment: podrías explicar un poco más la SOLUCIÓN, en que línea esta el segundo JSON y como es que lo solucionaste, eliminaste un JSON o los uniste en uno solo?